# Build errors on xamarin forms: Android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to build the code present at the following location-

https://scanbotsdk.github.io/documentation/barcode-scanner-sdk/xamarin/

I am trying to compile the solution 'ScanbotBarcodeSDKFormsExample.sln' on Visual Studio 2019 and it's giving me errors like (Attached screenshot)-

> resource attr/flow_horizontalSeparator (aka
> io.scanbot.example.sdk.barcode.xamarin.forms:attr/flow_horizontalSeparator)
> not found
>
> resource attr/flow_verticalSeparator (aka
> io.scanbot.example.sdk.barcode.xamarin.forms:attr/flow_verticalSeparator)
> not found

A couple of forums suggest changing the version of 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Constraint.Layout' but that is not working for me rather it's throwing an error stating the resource is used by another process. Any leads on this would be highly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: update xamarin forms nuget and target with latest SDK.

Comment: @Morse- Thanks for your quick response but its still giving the same errors. I have updated 'Xamarin.Forms' to latest available (4.8.0.1534) and 'ScanbotBarcodeSDK.Xamarin.Forms' is anyways targeting the latest version '1.0.2'.  Any other inputs please on this?

Comment: Seems like you did not update nuget for all projects. I will check once I get a chance.if bar code scanning is desired may I suggest `zxing forms` and the error message suggests some files getting trimmed from the native binding library. You will have to contact that team for the same.

Comment: @Morse- Thanks for your inputs. I was just wondering if you have used zxing forms and if you think that would be better to use? Would be great if you could share the sample code if you have used it. I have  put a comment on the github with same query hoping they reply soon.

Comment: @aroraarjita Hi, do you mean [this sample project](https://github.com/doo/scanbot-barcode-scanner-sdk-example-xamarin) from your shared link? If so, I have tested that, and it works.https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cgde2.png

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT- It's not working just the version of Xamarin.Android.Support.Constraint.Layout has been updated to 1.1.2 and it brings a Syste.IO.Exception 'File is being used by another process'(2nd screenshot above) though I do not have anything running which is using the process(I restarted the system and then gave a build) while if I revert the version it brings the other build errors(1st Screenshot above).

Comment: @aroraarjita Okey, I also used the 1.1.2 of `Xamarin.Android.Support.Constraint.Layout`, and it works. Whether pust the position of project is a short path? Such as : `E:\scanbot-barcode-scanner-sdk-example-xamarin-master`.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT- So I got a fix for the 2nd screenshot. Run processexp.exe (process explorer) as administrator and kill the process tree for devenv.exe and restart the visual studio 2019.

Comment: @aroraarjita That's great! You could update the solution in answer, then other people who has the same issue will know how to solve that.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT- Yep thanks. Have updated it.

Comment: @Morse- Thanks for your recommendation of zxing forms. I tried it and it's really cool to work on, quite easy and simple.

Comment: @Morse- I am working with Zxing now, but it gives the sacanned result in encoded formats like UPC-E. any idea how can I convert this to actual text? Like if I scan the same code in other scanner apps they give me a text from that number. e.g. In zxing I get -12772719 as a scanned result of a barcode but in other apps the result is CLOC. Any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the above error (1st screenshot)- Update Xamarin.Android.Support.Constraint.Layout to 1.1.2 and then it might bring a Syste.IO.Exception 'File is being used by another process'(2nd screenshot above) so to fix this you can run processexp.exe (process explorer) as administrator and kill the process tree for devenv.exe and restart the visual studio 2019. Then, build the solution and it should work sucessfully.

Actually what's happening is it is locking the process, may be a bug with visual studio so killing the process tree helps.